# iPhone Data Storage - understanding what is and what is not secure

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I am developing my first iPhone application and currently considering whether to deploy the app packaged with data, instead of calling upon a web service for the info.  The obvious benefits are for those situations where you have a poor/non-existent connection and i could easily write something that could update the client data periodically from within the app.

What i am not sure about is how to store the data - sqlite, core data, plist or iphone file structure - Simply because i dont want someone unzipping the deployed application and getting their hands on the raw data.

Is this actually feasable? or is pretty much everything accessible once its deployed as an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot stop somebody from accessing the data stored on the device, independently if you use sqlite, core data, plist or iphone file structure. At least not within reasonable means.

What you can do rather easily is to make the data useless for unauthorized access. In other words: encrypt it.

If what format you store the encrypted data then depends on the app needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty tough to do. The easiest way to do this would be by using the Xcode Organizer panel and then looking at the applications that you have installed. If it is one of your applications (matching your dev credentials) then Xcode will give you the option to download the application's sandboxed folders (docs, temp, etc).

From memory, you *cannot* do this to another application that doesn't belong to you. So in short you are safe to include data in your app. Honestly though, if someone wants to get to that data, they always will given enough time and resources (thats my opinion about all security).

Comment: You can unzip a .app file once you have purchased it and downloaded it from itunes using winrar or other unzip program.  Completely agree with your opinion on security!

Comment: Wow did not realize that, how do you get to that?